# What is the difference between the meaning of these two sentences and which one is the correct usage?

Tags: grammar, tenses

> "He jumped off the train while it had been running"
>   "He jumped off the train while it was running"

Comment: This is an ELU question. ***Both are correct***. Both. However, we say moving  not running.

Comment: @Lambie I think you mean ELL; however, I'd not consider the first example here correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh right, ELL, And it should be: after it had been moving, not while. I must asleep at the wheel....

Comment: @Elasthiccgirl Wait until you type fast.

Answer (score 1):

The first example has a contradiction in tenses; the second is more agreeable.

However the use of **running** isn't very good. We can say

> Trains run from City A to City B.
>
> The trains are running today.

The actual trains don't run — it is the *service* that runs. So in the context **moving** would be better, such as

> He jumped off the train while it was moving.
>
> He jumped off the train before it stopped.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the first sentence is contradicting ?

Comment: @user2393393 Though the past simple can be used twice in a sentence to show sequenced events (Elbonia, which fell/had fallen to the Dogberthans in 329 AE, made a brief recovery in the early 400s), using the past simple with a backshifted construction (He died while he had slept / had been sleeping // He died when the bullet had hit him) is unacceptable.